# Read data from Amazon sqs and write to s3 in Parquet format

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We have a use case where data for messages from different users are sent to the SQS, and we as a data team, want to subscribe to that queue and put data into S3, partitioned by time, so that we can due analysis on top of them.

What is the best way to consume those messages and write them to S3?

Something that I have in mind is using AWS lambda to put those messages to Firehose, and then use Firehose as a buffer, and once data is available for an a specific time period (let's say an hour), use Firehose to write it to S3 in Parquet format?

Is there any other solution? Maybe using AWS Glue or Data Pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Kinesis Firehose supports now JSON to Parquet (or ORC) conversion in a serverless manner - see here for the details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html